# SED - simple regexp needed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have the following string:

```
https://some.site/52d7e-8b88-0156426e1-audio=96000-481.m4s
```

I want it to become:

```
https://some.site/52d7e-8b88-0156426e1-audio=96000-\[1-481\].m4s
```

All I am doing is inserting a **"[1-"** before **the first digit in the final number** that occurs in the URL and **adding "]" before the final period**

What I tried?

```sh
echo "https://some.site/52d7e-8b88-0156426e1-audio=96000-481.m4s" \
         | awk -F'.' '{print $0"\\]."$NF}'|sed 's/.m4s//'
```

but I can't match the last number and change it

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: What about this one: `sed -E 's/-([0-9]+)\./-[1-\1]./'`, using GNU `sed` ?

Comment: Or more robust: `sed -E 's/-([0-9]+)\.([^.]*)$/-[1-\1].\2/'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "https://some.site/52d7e-8b88-0156426e1-audio=96000-481.m4s" | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\(\.m4s\)/\\[1-\1\\]\2/'
```